# can't Run rufus-3.17.exe on Linux Mint

Tags: rufus

I'm new in linux world and, trying to run rufus-3.17 on Linux mint but I keep on receiving error messages.
when using : "wine rufus-3.17.exe"
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\windows\system32\rufus-3.17.exe" not found

when using : "sudo apt-get install rufus"
i got the message: "sudo apt-get install rufus"

Can you please help hot run rufus, or if you have better idea on how to make bootable USB under Linux.
Thank you

Comment: `if you have better idea on how to make bootable USB under Linux` is an unrelated question ... please post separately

Answer (score 3):

[Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) is not available on Linux.  It is a Microsoft Windows *only* application.

There are alternatives like [Etcher](http://www.etcher.io/), Gnome Multi-Writer, Unetbootin, and many more for Linux.  Just [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20image%20writer&sxsrf=AOaemvLRpgxdrWA3VGfY1rSvrXM6iJbZJQ%3A1642102673298&ei=kX_gYc6wEaDSytMP1IKyuAw&ved=0ahUKEwiOvZqUva_1AhUgqXIEHVSBDMcQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=linux%20image%20writer&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBAgAEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAIEB46BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQgAEM0COgQIABANOgYIABANEB46CAgAEA0QBRAeOggIABAIEA0QHkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDbDFikOmDDPWgGcAJ4AIABYYgB6giSAQIxNJgBAKABAcgBCcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) for them.